# How do I integrate vanilla Javascript to a wordpress website?

Tags: php, css, javascript

I am new to WordPress but I have been learning to code since February. I am helping a friend add a responsive slider to her WordPress website. I created this slider using HTML, CSS and JS and it works perfectly. However, I am having problems integrating them into WordPress.

The JS code is

```
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const track = document.querySelector('.track');
const carouselWidth = document.querySelector('.carousel-container').offsetWidth;
let index = 0;
let initialPosition = null;
let moving = false;
let transform = 0;
next.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  index++;
  prev.classList.add('show');
  track.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * carouselWidth}px)`;
  if (track.offsetWidth - (index * carouselWidth) < carouselWidth) {
    next.classList.add('hide');
  }
});

prev.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  index--;
  next.classList.remove('hide');
  if (index === 0) {
    prev.classList.remove('show');
  }
  track.style.transform = `translateX(-${0}px)`
})



const gestureStart = (e) => {
  initialPosition = e.pageX;
  moving = true;
  const transformMatrix = window.getComputedStyle(track).getPropertyValue('transform');
  if (transformMatrix !== 'none') {
    transform = parseInt(transformMatrix.split(',')[4].trim());
  }
}

const gestureMove = (e) => {
  if (moving) {
    const currentPosition = e.pageX;
    const diff = currentPosition - initialPosition;
    track.style.transform = `translateX(${transform + diff}px)`;  
  }
};

const gestureEnd = (e) => {
  moving = false;
}

if (window.PointerEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('pointerdown', gestureStart);

  window.addEventListener('pointermove', gestureMove);

  window.addEventListener('pointerup', gestureEnd);  
} else {
  window.addEventListener('touchdown', gestureStart);

  window.addEventListener('touchmove', gestureMove);

  window.addEventListener('touchup', gestureEnd);  
  
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', gestureStart);

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', gestureMove);

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', gestureEnd);  
}
```

This is the code I added to the functions.php file. It adds all the CSS styles correctly.

```
function responsive_header(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive_header_css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/responsiveslider.css' , array() );
        wp_enqueue_script('responsive_header', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/responsiveslider.js', array(), '',  false);
    
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_header');
```

What is weird is that if I add a hello world alert to my script it works but nothing else works. Am i doing this wrong or must I use jquery. I dont know jquery but I can learn it to implement this.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery. Anything in the error console?

Comment: It says cannot read property offset width of null from the javascript file.

Comment: So it can't find `.carousel-container`. Did you wrap the code in a function call, waiting until the document is fully loaded?

Comment: All I had to do was change the true to false on the enqueue scripts function. I guess it loaded before the page loaded so it couldn't get information that's why it threw that error